# Count occurences in a row using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Consider the following relation

[image]

column `measured_at` holds thousands of different timestamps and column `cell_id` holds the number of the cell tower used at each timestamp. I want to query for each day saved in `measured_at`, which `cell tower` has the most occurences (used the most at that day, here is time irrelevant, only the date is to query). This probably can be done using window functions, but I want to do it using only aggregate functions and simple queries.
an output should look like for example:

```
cell_id       measured_at
27997442      2015-12-22
```

for the above example because on `22-12-2015` tower number `27997442` has been used the most.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use aggregation and `distinct on`.  To get the counts:

```
select date_trunc(date, measured_at) as dte, cell_id, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by dte, cell_id
```

And then extend this for only one value:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc(date, measured_at)) date_trunc(date, measured_at) as dte, cell_id, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by dte, cell_id
order by date_trunc(date, measured_at), count(*) desc;
```

Of course, you can use window functions as well -- and that is a better approach if you want to get ties as well:

```
select dte, cell_id, cnt
from (select date_trunc(date, measured_at) as dte, cell_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by date_trunc(date, measured_at) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by dte, cell_id
     ) dc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Isn't the first one also a window function? because we're using `count()` and `order by` at the same time